# Java 2D array storing many different types of data

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, 2d

This is my first Stack question.. so any help is appreciated(about posting style or given problem)

So.. I'm not really "new" in Java, but there are things that I don't know about it.

**I have a question about how to store following:
"Which of these is a fruit", "Orange", "Brick", "Tiger", "(and some kind of indication of right answer)".**

Bear in mind that there would be no more than 20 of theses kind of records, so i would put them in by hand statically not dynamically

I was thinking about using a 2d array, but how and will it work. My tutor also said that 2d arrays would be the best way to go ( i think he is expecting a 2d array even if there is a better way)... He also said that it MUST be as simple as possible so any fancy ways of Java must be hold off.

I could manage the 2d array part.. **but how do i indicate the right answer?** Some kind of Boolean with true or false?

The part about collecting answers from the user and checking is not that big of problem for me.

I would like your suggestions on how to deal with this task. Thank you!

p.s. it MUST be something that applet could handle
EDIT: 
ok guys .. i went whit 2d array here is code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Quiz_applet extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    static int rez = 0;
    static int c=0;
    static JTextField input = new JTextField(3);
    static String[][] data = {//q1 is in field data[0][0]
    {"q1", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A"},
    {"q2", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B"},
    {"q3", "A1", "A2", "A3", "C"},
    {"q4", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B"},
    {"q5", "A1", "A2", "A3", "C"},
    {"q6", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A"},
    {"q7", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A"},
    {"q8", "A1", "A2", "A3", "B"},
    {"q9", "A1", "A2", "A3", "C"},
    {"q10", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A"},
    {"q11", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A"}

    };
public void init() {     
    ShapeCanvas canvas = new ShapeCanvas();      
    JButton Button = new JButton("Answer!");
    Button.addActionListener(canvas);
    input.addActionListener(canvas);        
    JPanel bottom = new JPanel(); 
    bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,3,3));     
    bottom.add(Button);
    bottom.add(input);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(3,3));
    getContentPane().add("Center",canvas);              
    getContentPane().add("South",bottom);
    setSize(600,300);
}
static class ShapeCanvas extends JPanel
implements ActionListener {
    ShapeCanvas() {

}   
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

if(c==0){
    g.drawString(data[0][0], 50, 100);
    g.drawString(data[0][1], 50, 120);
    g.drawString(data[0][2], 50, 140);
    g.drawString(data[0][3], 50, 160);
}
else if(c!=0){
     g.drawString(data[c][0], 50, 100);
     g.drawString(data[c][1], 50, 120);
     g.drawString(data[c][2], 50, 140);
     g.drawString(data[c][3], 50, 160);
     //repaint();
}


}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
    }   

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
     String command = evt.getActionCommand();



    if (command.equals("Answer!"))
     {
         if(input.getText().equals(data[c][4]))
     {
     c=+1;
     rez=+1;
     };
         } ;


}
}
```

How to make question to change after i have clicked the answer button?
On other projects of mine it has worked something like this^.
p.s.2. I know the grid layout is bit "weird" but it works.. :)

Comment: So is this a set of questions with multiple choice answers? How do you feel about a `Question` object?

Comment: I would solve that with a Map<Fruit, Boolean>. As this gives you efficient lookup.

Comment: @Icewind I think thats just an example. I think the question could be more general than that. Such as the next one could be "Which is the largest number; 5, 12, 43"

Comment: About numbers... im not to sure.. i could get thru with normal string

Comment: How about a `class` with members `string question`, `string answer` and `java.util.List<string> dummies`? Maintain a list of those classes.

Comment: will look into Map @Icewind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a 2D array, you could make the last column the index of the correct answer. Then you would convert the index to an int and retrieve the correct answer:

**Format:**

question, choice1, choice2, choice3, correct index

**Sample records:**

"Which of these is a fruit", "Orange", "Brick", "Tiger", "1"

"Which of these is a car", "Turtle", "Volkswagen", "Mouse", "2"

In the first record, "1" is the array index for "Orange" (the correct answer). In the second record, "2" is the array index for "Volkswagen".

Comment: Yeah.. i went to sleep and got the same idea.... will work on it... Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Well there are certainly better ways of doing this such as using a Map which would allow you to map "Orange" -> true/false

However, if it must be a 2d array you can do the following:

```
private final String YES = "Y";
private final String NO = "N";

String[20][2] fruitData = new String[20][2]();

fruitData[0][0] = "Orange";
fruitData[0][1] = YES;

fruitData[1][0] = "Brick";
fruitData[1][1] = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of thing that makes sense as an object. That allows you to pair the question to answers in a way that makes sense. Its not a 2D array but theres nothing overly fancy here. You can then store these Question objects in a 1D array

```
public class Question {
    String question;
    List<String> allAnswers=new ArrayList<>();
    String correctAnswer;

    public Question(String question,String correctAnswer, List<String> wrongAnswers) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;

        allAnswers.addAll( wrongAnswers);

        //add the correct answer somewhere at random (so that when printing the options it isn't always the first one)
        Random rnd=new Random();
        allAnswers.add( rnd.nextInt(wrongAnswers.size()), correctAnswer);

    }

    public boolean isCorrectAnswer(String answer){
        return correctAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //string builder would be better but may constitute "fancy"
        String questionAsString= question;

        for(String answer: allAnswers){
            questionAsString=questionAsString+"\n";
            questionAsString=questionAsString+answer;
        }

        return questionAsString;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<String> incorrectAnswers=new ArrayList<>();
        incorrectAnswers.add("Brick");
        incorrectAnswers.add("Tiger");

        Question question=new Question("Which of these is a fruit","Orange", incorrectAnswers);

        System.out.println(question);

        System.out.println(); //just putting in a blank line

        System.out.println(question.isCorrectAnswer("Brick"));
        System.out.println(question.isCorrectAnswer("orange"));

    }


}
```

Comment: thanks.. my laptop is running low on battery.. i will check this when i get home. thank you all. Now i have some kind of clearness on what to do.